# unable to display file upload details in input using angular5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here I am using file ng2 file upload for uploading the files and till now I am able to get the file name and file details. But the issue is I want to display the file type and other details like file size and file name in input. Suppose I upload single file, assume '.jpeg' then filename:xxx.jpeg,filetype: image/jpeg has to show, and if I upload multiple types, i.e .jpeg,.jpeg,.png,.gif then .jpeg,.png,.gif. If the multiple files has same type then it simply has to show '' and other details like file name and file size. For single files it has to show details and for multiple files it has to show '' in input as I want to show it in input and though I am displaying '*' i want to get the multiple file names and file sizes.

```
.ts code:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FileUploader, FileUploadModule, FileItem } from 'ng2-file-upload';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  file_type='';
  file_size='';
  file_name='';
   private URL: string = 'https://evening-anchorage-3159.herokuapp.com/api/';
  public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({ url: this.URL });
  //const URL = 'https://evening-anchorage-3159.herokuapp.com/api/';
  //public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: URL});
  public hasBaseDropZoneOver:boolean = false;
  public hasAnotherDropZoneOver:boolean = false;

  public fileOverBase(e:any):void {
    this.hasBaseDropZoneOver = e;
  }

  public fileOverAnother(e:any):void {
    this.hasAnotherDropZoneOver = e;
  }

  constructor(){

    this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item: any, response: any, status: any, headers: any) => {

       console.log(item);
       for(var i=0;i <= item.FileItem.length;i++){
         console.log(i);

       }
      // this.file_name =item['file']['name'];
      // this.file_type = item['file']['type'];
      // this.file_size = item['file']['size'];
    }


  }
}

**.html code**


<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href> File Upload</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">

            <h3>Select files</h3>

            <div ng2FileDrop [ngClass]="{'nv-file-over': hasBaseDropZoneOver}" (fileOver)="fileOverBase($event)" [uploader]="uploader" class="well my-drop-zone">
                Base drop zone
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9" style="margin-bottom: 40px">

        <h3>Upload queue</h3>
        <p>Queue length: {{ uploader?.queue?.length }}</p>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="file_type">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="file_name">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="file_size">

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="50%">Name</th>
                    <th>Size</th>
                    <th>Progress</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of uploader.queue">
                    <td><strong>{{ item?.file?.name }}</strong></td>
                    <td *ngIf="uploader.isHTML5" nowrap>{{ item?.file?.size/1024/1024 | number:'.2' }} MB</td>
                    <td *ngIf="uploader.isHTML5">
                        <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': item.progress + '%' }"></div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <span *ngIf="item.isSuccess"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
                        <span *ngIf="item.isCancel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i></span>
                        <span *ngIf="item.isError"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>
                    </td>
                    <td nowrap>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" (click)="item.upload()" [disabled]="item.isReady || item.isUploading || item.isSuccess">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload
                    </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" (click)="item.cancel()" [disabled]="!item.isUploading">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Cancel
                    </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" (click)="item.remove()">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove
                    </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div>
            <div>
                Queue progress:
                <div class="progress" style="">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': uploader.progress + '%' }"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-s" (click)="uploader.uploadAll()" [disabled]="!uploader.getNotUploadedItems().length">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload all
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-s" (click)="uploader.cancelAll()" [disabled]="!uploader.isUploading">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Cancel all
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-s" (click)="uploader.clearQueue()" [disabled]="!uploader.queue.length">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove all
            </button>
        </div>

    </div>





</div>
```

my stackblitz working url

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mn3dvh

Comment: do you want to get these things?      // this.file_name =item['file']['name'];
      // this.file_type = item['file']['type'];
      // this.file_size = item['file']['size'];

Comment: @Asanka yeah i am storing these values as i have to display these in the input at present i commented it out

Comment: Ok if you get these 3 variables your problem solved? so i.ll try to get things done.

Comment: Yeah as i think u read my scenario suppose if have 1.jpeg,2.jpeg,3.png,5.jpg then in the input it has to display .jpeg,.png,.jpg it should group the repeated one's and suppose if the it got only same type i mean no other file type 1.jpeg,2.jpeg only then i should display '+'  and rest the of the fileds also  should display '+' and if click on the button i should be able to read the original values not the  '+'

Comment: input means where? where do you want to display type?

Comment: below the que length i already created input's and given ngmodel also there

Comment: ok. Do you want to input some thing? i mean your file types can be grouped and show,after that do you wnt to change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181453/discussion-between-asanka-and-madpop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This edited [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3hzuhp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) link may help you.Using 3 sets we can group type. Using this 3 set you can do what you want.

in .ts

```
  file_type : Set<string> = new Set<string>();
  file_size : Set<number> = new Set<number>();
  file_name : Set<string> = new Set<string>();

 public dropped(event:any) {

    for (var key = 0; key < event.length; key++) {
    let file = event[key];
      this.file_name.add(file.name)
      this.file_size.add(file.size)
      this.file_type.add(file.type)
}
```

In html

```
        <input type="text" [ngModel]="file_type.size>1?'*':file_type.values().next().value">
        <input type="text" [ngModel]="file_name.size>1?'*':file_name.values().next().value">
        <input type="text" [ngModel]="file_size.size>1?'*':file_size.values().next().value">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item: any, response: any, status: any, headers: any) => {

   console.log(item); 
   let arr:FileItem[]=[];
   arr.push(item)
  for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr.length > 1) {
      console.log(i);
      console.log('type is', arr[0].file.type);
      let type: string[] = [];
      type.push(arr[0].file.type);
      let temp: number = i;
      if (i != temp && arr[0].file.type) {
         //do something 
      }
    }
    else{          
      console.log('type is', arr[0].file.type);
    }
  }
  // this.file_name =item['file']['name'];
  // this.file_type = item['file']['type'];
  // this.file_size = item['file']['size'];
}
```

You can push the file object within the array and then access the 0th index of the property file which has the file type property, push these types in another array check if that array has duplicates do your processing, if there is only one uploaded file then directly access the `array[0].file.type` property and return it

Comment: i tried ur logic but i got repsonse 6 timesi i mean type is
image/png
type is
image/png
type is
image/jpeg
type is
image/jpeg
type is
image/jpeg
type is
image/jpeg